# Installing screen reader

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am creating new web page which includes accessibility control tools. Actually I am not web developer I am doing this because I fall in love with creating web pages. I have a question how I should include screen reader on my webpage?

Comment: A screen reader is a piece of software installed on your computer - not a webpage.

Comment: but some web pages have screen reader, I mean you select the area and press the read button or icon and that's that there is somebody who will be reading the text for you

Comment: Perhaps the [SpeechSynthesis API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis) could help you. Here is a basic example: https://codepen.io/SteveJRobertson/pen/emGWaR

Comment: OK, thanks. I think I got it. I found that if the user has default text to speech application then the user can use. I only can call that software if any exists.